# Independence of flipping a coin

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I have a coin that lands on heads with probability $N$ and tails with probability $1-N$. How do I explain the outcomes of the successive flips of the coin are independent of each other, knowing only $N$. Also if I didn't know the value of $N$, are the outcomes of the successive flips of the coin independent of each other?

Comment: That should be "lands **heads** with probability $N$ and tails with probability $1-N$", yes?

Comment: comment now redundant

Comment: @David Yes, corrected my question now. Thanks.

Comment: still $N-1$ instead of $1-N$

Comment: I went ahead and made the correction, since @orange confirmed he intended to write $1-N$.

Comment: It's rather unusual to use $N$ for denoting a fractional number. Apart from that, I don't understand the bit about "explain the successive flips of the coin are independent of each other"

Comment: @leonbloy I've changed the wording now. Is that better? That's all the information I have.

Comment: @leonbloy: I was just about to post the same thing re. showing independence. In principle, you can't show that coin flips are independent without further information about the flipping process. That said, I'm wondering if OP meant (or is allowed to implicitly assume) that the probability of a coin landing heads up after being flipped is $N$ *regardless of past events*. Of course this trivializes the conceptual problem, but perhaps OP is expected to note $P(A|B) = P(A)$ (or, say, to recognize that repeated coin flipping is a Bernoulli trial).

Comment: just for the record, this question is the exercise 13.14 of the book Artificial Intelligence a modern approach 3rd ed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm taking that *each* coin flip has $\mathbb{P}(\text{heads}) = N$ and $\mathbb{P}(\text{tails}) = 1-N$.

If two events A, B are independent, then $\mathbb{P}(A) = \mathbb{P}(A|B)$. Let $A$, $B$ be two successive coin flips. Then we can see that the coin flips must be independent given the above information.

Comment: the concept associate with the ℙ(A)=ℙ(A|B) is called marginal independence.